# Solve simultaneous equations with matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

$\begin{cases}
a-b+\lambda d=3
\\
-a+b-c=7
\\
-b+c-d=5
\\
\lambda a-c+d=4
\end{cases}$

With a certain value of $\lambda$ the simultaneous equations has infinitely many solutions. Define this $\lambda$-value and all solutions with that value of $\lambda$.

What I did:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & \lambda & 3
\\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 7
\\
0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 5
\\
\lambda & 0 & -1 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow$
$R_1=R_1+R_2\,\,,
\\
R_2=R_2+R_3\,\,,
\\
R_3=R_3+R_4$

$\Rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 & \lambda & 10
\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 12
\\
\lambda & -1 & 0 & 0 & 9
\\
\lambda & 0 & -1 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$

But I don't know how to go further from this. So how I get the value of $\lambda$ and solve all solutions with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be doing steps to get the first column to be $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\0\\0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: What do you mean, what steps?

Comment: Row reduction / gauss elimination

Comment: @RedRose: Gaussian Elimination, like the first one could be $R_2 = R_1 + R_2$.

Comment: Yes, I have done the $R_1=R_1+R_2$ as I have posted in my Q as [new equation 1]=...

Comment: And I know the Gauss elimination, but I don't get how I can get the value $\lambda$...because as what I have understood, with Gauss elimination you get values of the a, b, c, d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following row operations on the original matrix

1. $R_4 = R_4 + \lambda R_2$
2. $R_4 = R_4 + \lambda R_3$
3. $R_2 = R_2 + R_1$
4. $R_2 = R_2 + R_3$
5. $R_3 = R_3 - R_2$
6. $R_4 = R_4 + R_3$

After doing all these operations you will get last row as

[0  0  0   $1-2\lambda$ | $12\lambda-6$]

So for infinitely many solutions $\lambda$ should be 1/2 or 0.5
which will make whole last row as 0.

So 1/2 is the lambda value.

And then put the value of lambda to the matrix and then you can get infinite solutions for the system.

Hope it might help!

Comment: Very clear and informative answer :)

Comment: Hey btw what values did you get for a,b,c and d? Just to be sure if I did get right values.